# Dynamics CRM 2011 cannot register plugin to Disk

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am experimenting adding plugins to CRM2011 server. Following the steps of Plug-in Sample with the sdk, everything worked as expected. However, when I tried to register the plugin to Disk (the default is to Database), I got

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unable to load plug-in assembly.
```

Seemed that the server couldn't find the microsoft.xrm.sdk file. But why the same setting worked fine when publishing to Database?

I have added "write" privilege to user "Network Service" for folder C:\program files\MicrosoftDynamics CRM\Server\bin but got same error message.

The Server OS is Windows 2008 R2 Running inside a vmware player virtual machine.

Comment: I have asked this question at http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/5389fb9d-04ee-4a00-b7f5-48dc37a4e155 and hope to get some feedback from microsoft insiders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have got the answer from microsoft forum. Turned out that I need to manually copy the dll over to CRM server under CRMINSTLLDIR/Server/bin/assembly then I can do the registration from my client machine.

Now that I know the concept but still think it anti-intuitive. Is there any reason that Microsoft designed its plugin registration process this way? Security?

Comment: We had this same issue. We ended up doing exactly what you did. I'm not sure why they did it either. We just stuck with putting it in the DB while developing (uploading the dll every time is a pain).

Answer (score 0):

If you try adding group "Everyone" with full access to the bin folder, do you still get the error?

Comment: Now I added Everyone with full control. Still gets the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

One does seem to be stuck with registering the .dll in the CRM database once that selection has been made, so one cannot then start using the assembly folder (disk) after that.

I've sort off gone with always using disk when dev'ing so one can quickly update just the assembly and only use the database option in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to deploy to disk try this:

1. Create a share on the […]/Server/bin/assembly folder with read/write for just the developer.  Alternatively if the developer has admin rights on the server you can skip this step and just use the admin share.  For example: 
   \servername\c$\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin\assembly
2. In Visual Studio, under the Project/Properties menu selection, in the *Post-build event command line* box, add a command to copy your .dll (and .pdb if debugging).   The copy command should include either the share name created in the previous step, or the path using the admin$

Also, take a look at the macros available under the Edit Post-build button.  You will find some useful bits like $(TargetFileName) to abstract actual file and folder names.

Now every time you build, your files will automatically be copied to the server.

Even though I register my plugin to the database, I use this method all the time.  If you want to do any remote debugging you will need the .dll and .pdb in the assembly folder on the server.